# sdkman installed grails 4.0.4, now grails is broken and wont start

Tags: macos, grails, sdkman

I have some older version of grails installed (3.3.8), and tried to use sdkman to install a newer version (4.0.4). The install worked, but grails is now completely broken.  i also updated java to 14 from the dmg from the oracle website.  Basically grails is now completely broken. Any ideas how to fix?

mac 10.14.4

```
$ sdk version
  SDKMAN 5.7.3+337

$ sdk current java
  Not using any version of java

$ java -version
  java version "14.0.2" 2020-07-14
  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.2+12-46)
  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.2+12-46, mixed mode, sharing)

$ sdk current
  Using:
  groovy: 2.5.8

$ grails --version
  | Grails Version: 3.3.8
  | Groovy Version: 2.4.15
  | JVM Version: 14.0.2

$ sdk install grails
Downloading: grails 4.0.4
In progress...
######################################################################## 100.0%
Installing: grails 4.0.4
Done installing!
Setting grails 4.0.4 as default.

$ sdk current
 Using:
 groovy: 2.5.8

 $ grails --version
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7
    at org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.VMPluginFactory.<clinit>(VMPluginFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.GroovyClassValueFactory.<clinit>(GroovyClassValueFactory.java:35)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.<clinit>(ClassInfo.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:95)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.<clinit>(ReflectionCache.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.registerMethods(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
    at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.NumberNumberMetaMethod.<clinit>(NumberNumberMetaMethod.java:33)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:124)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:346)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:604)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.createMetaMethodFromClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.<init>(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at groovy.lang.GroovySystem.<clinit>(GroovySystem.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.<clinit>(InvokerHelper.java:86)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.bitwiseNegate(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:842)
    at org.grails.config.NavigableMap.<clinit>(NavigableMap.groovy)
    at org.grails.cli.GrailsCli.<clinit>(GrailsCli.groovy:77)
```

I dont see an easy way to uninstall java 14, or go back in time.

```
echo $PATH
/Users/xx/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/current/bin:/Users/xx/.sdkman/candidates/grails/current/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Appz/apache-jmeter-5.3/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/opt/X11/bin:~/.dotnet/tools:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Users/xx/go/bin:/Users/xx/dev/grails-3.3.8/bin:/Users/xx/dev/flutter/bin:/Users/xx/dev/gradle-5.1.1/bin:/appz/cassandra/bin
```

I am guessing I can try to hack the path etc, to fix.

This is my current .bash_profile:

```
vi .bash_profile

export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`
export GRAILS_HOME=/Users/xx/dev/grails-3.3.8

export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
export PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export GRADLE_HOME=/Users/xx/dev/gradle-5.1.1
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
PATH="${PATH}:/Users/xx/dev/flutter/bin"
PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/bin


# Cassandra
if [ -d "/appz/cassandra" ]; then
    export PATH="$PATH:/appz/cassandra/bin"
fi

export PATH

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/simonh/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/xx/.sdkman/xx/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/xx/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
~
```

This is odd, why is grails home still 3.3.8, when sdkman installed and made 4.0.4 current?  Why didnt it edit the path?  What version should I set gradle to?  How do I go back to java 8, as I think there are bugs in java 14 which is causing issues with grails?

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out.

First, I had to manually fix the java version.

To do this go to

```
 $ /usr/libexec
 $ ./java_home -V
```

This outputs one or more versions:

```
14.0.2, x86_64: "Java SE 14.0.2"    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home
1.8.0_131, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Now edit our .bash_profile and replace the JAVA_HOME line with the version you want, either the whole thing (1.8.0_131) or just the major (1.8) thusly:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

Now when you open a new window, and do "java -version" you get 1.8, and when you do "grails -version" I finally get 4.0.4.

Yay!

The strange part is that just changing JAVA_HOME should not affect whats on the path, but it seems to.  i.e. just setting JAVA_HOME should not affect what version of java is run when I type in "java", but it does.  i.e. there is no line suchy as "PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin in muy bash_profile.